# My JSON data is only being populated into one ul element instead of each ul element

Tags: javascript, html, json, nav

I have an object that stores each menu title and has the links that should go under each respective title. The problem that I am having is that all of the links are going under the first ul element and not each ul element. This(data.Items[x].Children[y].Title) should populate under each menu title. My code is below:

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <footer>
    <div id="footerOverlay">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="footer-content">
                    <div class="footer-left">
                        <div class="footer-left__menu">
                            <div class="row">           
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer-right"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        </footer>
        <script>
        data =
    {
      "Items": [
        {
          "Title": "Fitness & Training",
          "Url": "/club-resources",
          "Children": [
            {
              "Title": "Find a Club/Coach",
              "Url": "/club-resources"
            },
            {
              "Title": "Drills and Technique",
              "Url": "/fitness-and-training/drills-and-technique"
            },
            {
              "Title": "Articles and Videos",
              "Url": "/fitness-and-training/articles-and-videos"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Title": "Events",
          "Url": "/events",
          "Children": [
            {
              "Title": "Fitness Events",
              "Url": "/events/fitness-events"
            },
            {
              "Title": "Clinics",
              "Url": ""
            },
            {
              "Title": "Results",
              "Url": "/comp/meets/"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Title": "About",
          "Url": "/about-us",
          "Children": [
            {
              "Title": "About Us",
              "Url": "/about-us/"
            },
            {
              "Title": "Partners",
              "Url": "sponsor-partners"
            },
            {
              "Title": "Contact Us",
              "Url": "/contact-us"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Title": "Join",
          "Url": "/register1",
          "Children": [
            {
              "Title": "Join Now",
              "Url": "/register1"
            },
            {
              "Title": "Renew Now",
              "Url": "/renew"
            },
            {
              "Title": "Products & Discounts",
              "Url": "/products-and-discounts"
            }     
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
            var numOfItems = data.Items.length, footerRow = document.querySelector(".footer-left__menu > .row");
            footerRow.innerHTML = "";
            for(x = 0; x < numOfItems; x++)
            {
                footerRow.innerHTML += "<h3 class='footer-menu__header'>" + data.Items[x].Title + "</h3>";
                footerRow.innerHTML += "<ul class='footer-menu__list list--nostyle'>";
                footerRow.innerHTML += "</ul>";
                for(y = 0; y < data.Items[x].Children.length; y++){
                    document.querySelector(".footer-menu__list.list--nostyle").innerHTML += 
"<li><a href=''>" + data.Items[x].Children[y].Title + "</a></li>";
                }
                }

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: There's no JSON in this question, just an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only selecting the first `ul` element. Instead, use querySelectorAll and the x index to get the current one.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".footer-menu__list.list--nostyle")[x]...
```

Comment: @sjw0525 - if this does answer your question to your satisfaction and you desire not other/new answers please accept this one as it will then show as answered and allow others to focus on unanswered questions.